# Invalid Branch Characters

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo

I am using SonarQube with the following tools (Bitbucket Server, Bamboo and Slack). After upgrading to v6.3 all the links were broken. For instance a url on Sonar4Bamboo that links directly to SonarQube does not work, unless I manually replace the "/" with a "%2F".

For Example:

**Slack**

```
http://localhost:9000/overview?id=com.myproject.group:master **(Not Working)**
http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=com.myproject.group:master **(Works)**
```

**Sonar4Bamboo**

```
http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/com.myproject.group:feature/SONAR-7000 **(Not Working)**
http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/com.myproject.group:feature%2FSONAR-7000 **(Works)**
```

**Sonar for Bitbucket**

```
An error occurred while getting data from Sonar Unknown Error

2017.03.24 17:32:16 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.w.RootFilter] Processing of request /api/duplications/show?   key=com.myproject.group:feature%2FSONAR-7000%3Asrc%2Fmain%2Fscripts%2Frelease.sh failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call reset() after response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.reset(ResponseFacade.java:347)
at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletResponse$ServletStream.reset(ServletResponse.java:79)
at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.sendErrors(WebServiceEngine.java:135)
at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:109)
at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:85)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:76)
at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:72)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RoutesFilter.doFilter(RoutesFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more precise? What issue do you get? Things are working properly on SonarQube.com that is in 6.3 version. For instance: https://sonarqube.com/dashboard?id=org.travis_sonar.samples%3Atravis_sonar

Comment: I am using SonarQube with the following tools (Bitbucket Server, Bamboo and Slack). After upgrading to v6.3 all the links were broken.

For instance a url on Sonar4Bamboo that links directly to SonarQube does not work, unless I manually replace the "/" with a "%2F".

I think it has to do with the project key

Comment: Can you update your question and give the precise list of URL that don't work please?

Comment: Please check update above

Comment: You might get some help from the Sonar4Bamboo vendor, it's possible there's a bug in the add-on you're using. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ch.mibex.bamboo.sonar4bamboo/server/support

Comment: Thanks @Rog, The issue was caused by a deprecated API call. Issue resolved with vendors